# Can you dynamically rename a class name?

Tags: java

Is it possible in Java to give a class or even its functions a new name at run time. By reading in the new names as arguments or on a configuration file when the program is started?

UPDATE:

Here is the purpose of this. I am using Java Script Engine to allow any JSR 223 compatible Scripting Language to access our API. Some of our clients are not used to using Java and it's naming conventions and would feel more comfortable using their own specific naming conventions. So I am required to give them the capability to dynamically change the API's class and function names without actually changing them in the code. It was suggested I use a Map and some sort of binding with a string name and the actual Java name e.g.,

```
    map.put("Hello",HelloWorld.class)

    Object obj = new Hello();
```

which should be the same as,

```
    Object obj = new HelloWorld();
```

If this is not possible please tell me why. I need a solid Java expertise answer. This is out of my league and I need facts to tell people why this is not possible even though myself I am almost sure it's not possible.

Possible Solution:

Here is the closets solution I have come up with. Using this link,
https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2005/08/10/reflection-and-dynamically-changing-classes
I could add in the names at run time, use composition to create an Adapter Class, and then compile the file, and voila the Script Language folks could use their defined names instead of my API's Java names.

Is this the only conceivable way to accomplish this?

UPDATE 2:

Here is another possible solution for anyone trying this too,

http://asm.ow2.org/doc/faq.html

That'll take you directly to their frequently asked questions which will have one for this exact problem.

Comment: i don't think so...but just wanted to ask why do you need to rename your class names?

Comment: There's probably a better design pattern than the one you're thinking of if you need dynamic *class* names

Comment: Sounds like a XY problem (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) - what are you trying to do/solve?

Comment: No. But why would you need to rename classes?

Comment: Back up.  What are you trying to solve?

Comment: Everyone I've updated my question. This all has to do with one small fact. I am allowing people unfamiliar with Java to use their Scripting Languages to access our API. I need to give them a way to feel comfortable with our concrete naming conventions and it was decided that I give them a dynamic way to change the names and somehow bind the two names. This is the closets solution I have come up with https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2005/08/10/reflection-and-dynamically-changing-classes and I would use composition to create an adapter class while adding in their specific names at run time.

Comment: It's silly to try to implement dynamic class naming for something like that

Comment: Silly? Or not possible. Can I have a solid answer please.

Comment: Not possible in a direct manner, you'd be recompiling every time. If you put a house at the address `42 Wallaby Way, Australia`, you can't just mail a package to Asia and expect it to arrive in the correct location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you will need to refactor for references and recompile for execution.

Comment: So just to clarify, even if I wanted to I could not do this? Not with Reflection or ScriptEnine or any sort of Binding at all?

Comment: What about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897685/dynamic-loading-a-class-in-java-with-a-different-package-name?rq=1 or is that only for packages.

Comment: @codeMonkey you could extend all your classes with the names that you want and override all the methods with only a super on them, but still, not at run time.

Comment: @codeMonkey with ASM you aren't renaming the class per se, you're recreating it. But for your porposes it could work.

Comment: thanks for the solid answers. Your second comment above sounds like my idea using this technique https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2005/08/10/reflection-and-dynamically-changing-classes but I could use composition or inheritance like you said and create an adapter class.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you are able to do that using javassist. 
In particular, you have to edit NewExpr.